# React - interact with child component

Tags: reactjs, oop, typescript, encapsulation

I would like to know what is the best practice for parent-child component interaction and whether the following approach satisfies good practices.

Let's say that we have two components: `Parent` and `Child`, where Parent gets handlers on Child in a fashion similar to that of obtaining a ref on element.

```
class Parent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

  private handlers: {
    Child: ChildHandlers
    /** And so on... **/
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child handlers={(handlers: ChildHandlers) => { this.handlers.Child = handlers; }} />
        <button onClick={() => this.handlers.Child.toggle() /** Or change Parent.state and then trigger **/}>toggle from parent</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component<ChildProps, ChildState> {
  constructor(props: ChildProps) {
    super(props);

    this.exposeHandlers();
  }

  private toggle(): void {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
  }

  private exposeHandlers() {
    let handlers: ChildHandlers = {
      toggle: () => this.toggle()
    };

    this.props.handlers(handlers);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.visible && (
          <div>
            <h2>I'm being toggled!</h2>
            <button onClick={() => this.toggle()} />toggle from child<button>
          </div>
        ) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It seems to be fine because:

- It allows to be consistent
- It's like exposing an interface used by both components without coupling them too much
- It's keeping Child's state out of Parent's business to a reasonable extent
- It's easier then to add callback to `toggle` method to perform some actions on Parent after updating Child's state.

But since I'm not experienced, are there any (even slightest) problems with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an overkill to me.

What's wrong with exposing those methods and just having a reference in `Parent` to an instance of `Child` and then invoke those methods when needed?

Parent:

```
class Parent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    private child: Child;

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Child ref={ el => this.child = el } />
            <button onClick={() => this.child.toggle()}>toggle from parent</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Child:

```
class Child extends React.Component<{}, ChildState> {
    public toggle(): void {
        this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.visible) {
            return <div />;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h2>I'm being toggled!</h2>
                    <button onClick={() => this.toggle()}>toggle from child</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It definitely is an overkill - didn't know about the ability to access Child directly. Thanks!